# pandas MultiIndex with duplicate values in one level

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I need to replace the values of one level of pandas MultiIndex with another set of values. This is easily done with **set_levels** unless the new set contains duplicates, i.e. two or more values from the original set of level values are mapped to the same value in the new set. Doing so results in error. There is a brute force way of making this work by getting all index values (instead of levels) as MultiIndex of tuples, mapping to the new level in this space, then replacing the original index with a new MultiIndex constructed with **from_tuples** method. Is there a better way?
[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample MaultiIndex data to question with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `rename` with specify level of `MultiIndex` for set new values to same duplicated values, e.g. for processing first level:

```
d = {'orig1': 'a', 'orig2':'a'}

df = df.rename(index=d, level=0)
```

Comment: Added code to better demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set a level without verifying integrity and then convert to new index. For example if you want to set values of level 1 to new_values_level_1 then you can do something like this:

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.set_levels(new_values_level_1,1,verify_integrity=False).values)