# Replace singular value on second level of pandas dataframe multiindex when that index level has identical values

Tags: python, pandas, rename, multi-index, reindex

I have a dataframe that has a multiindex with two levels. Given the following example for the second level:

```
d = {
"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"col2": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"col3": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"col4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"col5": [1, 2, 3, 4],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ["identical"]])
```

How do I change a singular value so that the second level of the index looks like this?

```
['example', 'identical', 'identical', 'identical', 'identical']
```

I have tried to do it this way:

```
        updated_columns = list(df.columns.get_level_values(1))

        updated_columns[0] = 'example'

        df.columns.set_levels(
            updated_columns, level=1, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False
        )
```

My change is ignored in this case.

I have also tried the answer from this topic: [pandas MultiIndex with duplicate values in one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015624/pandas-multiindex-with-duplicate-values-in-one-level)

```
        df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
            df.columns.set_levels(updated_columns, 1, verify_integrity=False).values
        )
```

Which was also ignored.

I have also considered using the rename() method. Unfortunately it only works if the value of the column that is renamed is provided. Given that there are identical values, this will not work.

For non-multiindexes there is this method:

```
df.columns.values[0] = 'example'
```

But from what I have gathered, it will not work for a multi index.

I have added verify_integrity=False because the method would not otherwise allow me to set identical values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will you please provide a bit of sample code to create the MultiIndex, just to make sure we're on the same page?

Comment: Yes of course. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to get the tuples that make up the MultiIndex and modify them directly:

```
    tuples = df.columns.tolist()
    tuples[0] = (tuples[0][0], 'example')

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
  example identical identical identical identical
0       1         1         1         1         1
1       2         2         2         2         2
2       3         3         3         3         3
3       4         4         4         4         4
```

---

MultiIndexes are a bit weird. They're stored as a list of levels (which contain *unique* label values), and codes (which are the indexes of the labels). For example, the levels and codes for your current MultiIndex look like this:

```
>>> df.columns.levels
FrozenList([['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], ['identical']])

>>> df.columns.codes
FrozenList([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

As you can see, there's only one `'indentical'` string in there. The repetitions of it are defined by the codes.

So if you wanted to set the first label of the second level to `example` by manipulating the levels and codes, you might go about it like this:

```
vals = df.columns.levels[1].tolist()
vals.append('example')

df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(vals, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.set_codes([1, 0, 0, 0, 0], level=1) # 1 = 'example', 2 = 'identical'
```

---

Here's a function that you can use to set all the labels of a particular level of a MultiIndex:

```
def set_level_of_df(df, level_index, labels):
    new_df = df.copy()
    
    unique, inverse = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)
    new_df.columns = new_df.columns.set_levels(unique, level=level_index)
    new_df.columns = new_df.columns.set_codes(inverse, level=level_index)
    return new_df
```

Usage:

```
>>> df
     col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
  example identical identical identical identical
0       1         1         1         1         1
1       2         2         2         2         2
2       3         3         3         3         3
3       4         4         4         4         4

>>> df = set_level_of_df(df, level_index=0, labels=['aaa', 'abc', 'xyz', '0123', '-----'])
>>> df
      aaa       abc       xyz      0123     -----
  example identical identical identical identical
0       1         1         1         1         1
1       2         2         2         2         2
2       3         3         3         3         3
3       4         4         4         4         4
```

Here's another function (which uses the previous one) that you can use to set a particular label of a particular level of a MultiIndex (which is your question):

```
def set_label_of_label_of_df(df, level_index, label_index, label):
    new_df = df.copy()
    
    labels = df.columns.get_level_values(level=level_index).tolist()
    labels[label_index] = label
    return set_level_of_df(df, level_index, labels)
```

Usage:

```
>>> df
     col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
  example identical identical identical identical
0       1         1         1         1         1
1       2         2         2         2         2
2       3         3         3         3         3
3       4         4         4         4         4

>>> df = set_label_of_label_of_df(df, level_index=1, label_index=3, label='THIS_IS_A_TEST_VALUE')
>>> df
     col1      col2      col3                 col4      col5
  example identical identical THIS_IS_A_TEST_VALUE identical
0       1         1         1                    1         1
1       2         2         2                    2         2
2       3         3         3                    3         3
3       4         4         4                    4         4
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you don't mind, stay tuned, because I'm working on an update to this answer that I'll deliver in a few minutes :)

Comment: There we go. Check the very bottom of the answer for a convenient function to do exactly what you were originally intending in one intuitive line. :)

Comment: Very convenient. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. This is actually quite a masterpiece compared to what I usually do...I'm going to put it on my profile as underrated :D

Comment: It is a very convenient solution and it is much appreciated. I am not yet sure if it will be suitable for my specific use case because the dataframe I am working with is stored as a class property. It is the basis for several model views. Therefore I do not know if copying and overwriting the entire thing every time I want to change one specific value in an index will be a worthwile thing to do. I may run into issues with the model views. It may also not be very performant for larger data sets. I will look into it in detail tomorrow. The original solution works great for my use case.