# Multi level columns in pandas and removing unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so with multi level columns

[image]

This is really annoying for example, `Web Development, Data Science, Data Analytics, Cyber Security, IOS, Blockchain, Other (Please Specify)` are all nested column children of the parent column `test_col`.

So if I wanted to query for example `Data Science` count values Id have to go

`df["Unnamed: 14"]["Data Science"].notnull().sum()`

What I would like to do is remove the "Unnamed: #" for either column level and nest them appropriately so I could do something like this:

`df["test_col"]["Data Science"]`

or

`df["Where do you live?"]["living outside Canada (please specify)"].notnull().sum()`

How do I combined multi level columns into nested columns?

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday I wrote [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461071) to replace labels of a level of a MultiIndex!

```
def set_level_of_df(df, level_index, labels):
    new_df = df.copy()
    
    unique, inverse = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)
    new_df.columns = new_df.columns.set_codes(inverse, level=level_index)
    new_df.columns = new_df.columns.set_levels(unique, level=level_index)
    return new_df
```

Now just use it:

```
i = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
new_vals = i.where(~i.str.startswith('Unnamed: '), 'test_col')
df = set_level_of_df(df, 0, new_vals)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work but after I run your code above then run.

`df["test_col"]` I get the error `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

I tried `df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]` and `df.reset_index()`

But I keep getting `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`
Any ideas?